# How to set UITableViewCell background color like the Settings app in tvOS

Tags: uitableview, tvos

In the tvOS Settings app, each cell of the table has a background that's visible but translucent, as shown below. How do I get the same in my own app? Is there a specific `UIColor` value to set for the `backgroundColor` property of `UITableViewCell`?

For example, you can see that in the Settings app, the `General` row has a cell background that makes it standout from the view background:
[image: Settings App]

However in my app where I used a UITableView, the `Clock Display` row does NOT have any background for the cell:
[image: My App]

My table cells are created using this line, without setting any colors:

> [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Answer (score 0):

In tvOS this is the “Default” color, which will change automatically for light/dark styles.

However you can also use `UIVisualEffectView` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uivisualeffectview).

Comment: Sorry I may not have described the issue clearly before, please see my updated description above.